# FFmpeg video conversion wont play in my browser

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I am trying no matter what format of video my clients upload to convert them into three different formats:

```
 var videoExtensions = ['mp4', 'webm', 'ogg'];

    var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
videoExtensions.forEach(function (extension) {
    var proc = new ffmpeg({source: media.file.path, nolog: false})
        .withVideoCodec('libx264')
        .withVideoBitrate(800)
        .withAudioCodec('libvo_aacenc')
        .withAudioBitrate('128k')
        .withAudioChannels(2)
        .toFormat(extension)
        .saveToFile(media.targetDir + media.getName() + '.' + extension,
        function (retcode, error) {
            console.log('file has been converted succesfully');
        });
});
```

On my local machine I am able to open and play the videos no problem

However as soon as I load them as resources into my browser it simply will not play.

If I however instead of converting just move the file I have no problem opening the file in my browser however then I will not be able to get the file in all three formats.

My question is am I doing something wrong in the above code or why is my browser "rejecting" the files so to speak?

Comment: There are too many factors here to provide an answer. What `ffmpeg` commands were used to create the videos? What does the complete `ffmpeg` console output show for each encoding command? How are you trying to get the browsers to play the videos? Can you provide samples of the videos that do not play?

Comment: Hmm there is no real console output